# Radio button not showing on mustache

Tags: html, radio-button, mustache

I have the line of code below. Im wondering why the radio button is not showing. Im using mustache

[image]

```
<table>
    <tbody>                                      
        <tr>
            {{#optionValues}}
               <td align="center"  class = "carpetQualityImg">
               <a  class="optionSelect carpetQualityOptions" data-id="{{id}}" 
                                                        data-label="{{trimmedLabel}}" 
                                                        onclick="{{trimmedLabel}}('{{id}}','{{imageUrl}}','{{label}}','{{formattedPrice}}','{{code}}')" 
                                                        data-text="{{label}}" 
                                                        data-price="{{formattedPrice}}" 
                                                        data-value="{{imageUrl}}">{{label}}</a> 
                <input type="radio" name="{{rdCarpetQuality}}" value="{{label}}">{{label}}
              </td>
            {{/optionValues}}
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why you post image of snipped instead of raw code?

Comment: Please provide markup + JS object at the very least